# excel vba linking a command to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, commandbutton

I have an ActiveX button on sheet1 but my goal seek formula is on sheet2. When I run it, the cells in column N of sheet2 are not changed. Can anyone fix the code for me?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

With Worksheets("sheet2")
For J = 23 To 26
      Cells(J, "o").GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Cells(J, "n")
Next J

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Explain in what way it doesn't work.

Comment: @Alan - the fact that the code is doing a goal seek on sheet1 (because that is the `ActiveSheet` when the button is pressed) but the question says that the goal seek formula is on sheet2 means "it doesn't work" in this case refers to "the goal seek isn't being performed"

Answer (score 2):

Because you never qualify your `Cells` properties with which worksheet they are referring to, they default to referring to `ActiveSheet` (which will be the sheet on which your button is located), and so your current code is equivalent to

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim J As Variant
    For J = 23 To 26
        ActiveSheet.Cells(J, "o").GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=ActiveSheet.Cells(J, "n")
    Next J
End Sub
```

You have also included a `With Worksheets("sheet2")` block in your code, but you never make use of it.

---

The easiest way to fix your issue is simply to ensure that you qualify which worksheet is being referred to and, because you already have a `With Worksheets("sheet2")` block already in your code, that just means adding the `.` to specify that your `With` object is the qualifier of each of your `Cells` properties:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

With Worksheets("sheet2")
For J = 23 To 26
      .Cells(J, "o").GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=.Cells(J, "n")
Next J

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, YowE3K. After adding . the error message doesn't show anymore but the goalseek is still not done on sheet2. Any idea why?

Comment: @peterjohn (a) What error message were you getting?  I assumed it simply wasn't working and even voted to re-open the question on the assumption that there was no error.  You had better edit the question yourself then to explain what "it just doesn't work" means.  (b) The edited code worked for me, but it will depend on what formulas you have on sheet2 which are calculating Sheet2!O23 (etc) based on Sheet2!N23 (etc).